# How to divide one select with another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables this is the first

```
select jmeno, prijmeni,
CAST(pr_o as float) cislo from(select jmeno, prijmeni, COUNT(id_objednavky) pr_o
from Objednavky o join Zamestnanci z 
on z.ID_Zamestnance=o.ID_zamestnance
where YEAR(datum_odeslani)=2010
group by jmeno, prijmeni)aa
```

this is the second

```
select AVG(pocet) prumer_o  from(
select jmeno, prijmeni,count(id_objednavky) pocet
from Objednavky o join Zamestnanci z 
on z.ID_Zamestnance=o.ID_zamestnance
where year(datum_odeslani)=2010
group by Jmeno, prijmeni
)aaa
```

What i want is one table with 3 columns: Jmeno, Prijmeni, Cislo (First table) divide by prumer_o (Second table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to do it in only one query. Try this:

```
SELECT jmeno, 
       prijmeni, 
       CAST(pr_o AS FLOAT)/(AVG(pr_o) OVER()) div
FROM   (SELECT jmeno, 
               prijmeni, 
               COUNT(id_objednavky) pr_o 
        FROM   objednavky o 
               JOIN zamestnanci z 
                 ON z.id_zamestnance = o.id_zamestnance 
        WHERE  YEAR(datum_odeslani) = 2010 
        GROUP  BY jmeno, 
                  prijmeni)aa
```